# Send image from iPhone to .net server

Tags: c#, iphone, .net, objective-c

I want to send image from my iPhone to the server(.net)

On the iPhone side i send the image with this method:

```
UIImage *myImg = ((UserData*)[UserData sharedUserData]).image;
NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(myImg, 0.5);

imageRequest = [ASIFormDataRequest requestWithURL:url];
[imageRequest addData:imageData withFileName:@"someFileName.jpeg" andContentType:@"image/jpeg" forKey:@"uploadedImage"];
[imageRequest setDelegate:self];
[imageRequest setRequestMethod:@"POST"];
[imageRequest startAsynchronous];
```

And in the serverside this is :

```
string input = null;

using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(Request.InputStream))
{
       input = sr.ReadToEnd();
}

Response.Write(input);
return;
```

and then when i print the `input` i get:

```
--0xKhTmLbOuNdArY-62D4D088-0CE1-4D32-BE57-2ED976BDF9FE
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="uploadedImage"; filename="someFileName.jpeg"
Content-Type: image/jpeg

����
```

Now my problem is that i can't save the image to my disk in the server, i didn't found the answer for this in any place.

Answer (score 0):

Your Objective-C code looks fine, I did some Google-fu and found this guide for ASP.net:
http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/working-with-http/sending-html-form-data,-part-2

It seems to me that this is what you are trying to do, so I hope this helps.